# How to create this `check constraint`

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

`People`:

```
Id | OrgId | Name
-----------------
 1    10      Sam
 2    10      Dana
 3    12      Max
```

`Id` is a primary key.  `OrgId` is foreign key to other table.

And second table `Cars`:

```
Id | Name | OrgId | PersonId 
----------------------------
1    Volvo   10        1
2    BMW     10        2
```

Here: `Id` is a primary key.  `PersonId` is a foreign key to `People` table. `OrgId` is foreign key to `Organization` table.

So I have `Person` which are attached to `Organization` and I have `Cars` which are attached to `Organization` and `Person`.

I need to guarantee that it will be impossible to attach `Car` from one `Organization` to `Person` from another `Organization`.  The record:

```
Id | Name | OrgId | PersonId 
----------------------------
1    Volvo   12        1
```

must be impossible because `Car` belongs to `Organization` with `ID` = 12, but `Person` belongs to `Organization` with `ID` = 10.

What is the best way to do it ?

I see two ways:

1. Foreign key using two fields `People` (`Id` + `OrgId`) <-> `Cars` (`PersonId` + `OrgId`).

But in this case I need to create one additional unique index on the table `People` ('Id`+`OrgId`).

2. Trigger on the table `Cars`.

What do you recommend to use in this case ?

Comment: I would go with the first option.

Comment: This is a faq, which you & all the other askers would find the answer to if you actually expressed what you were doing in a search. Google my comments re googling many versions of you question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction is to look up the organization using the person column.  But, that doesn't really fit the situation -- cars are owned by organizations independently of people.  So, you might need the organization, even if no person is assigned.

So, add a new key to `people`:

```
alter table people add constraint unq_people_orgid_id unique (orgid, id);
```

Then use this for the foreign key reference in `cars`:

```
alter table cars add constraint
    foreign key (orgid, personid) references people(orgid, id);
```

Note that the second key *is* redundant.  But it allows a reference that includes the organization.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use OrgId in your cars table, it violates normalization rules.  You can use a query to get the organization information for the car using the PersonId.

Comment: The `Car` can have `NULL` value in the `PersonId` column (the is no driver), but this `Car` still have value in the `OrgId` column (as the car belongs to this organization). So I don't see denormalization here.

Comment: @demas good point, should have thought through this better before trying to answer.